# Erase external SD card via adb

Tags: adb, external-sd, partitions, formatting

Is it possible to perform "Erase external SD card" action via `adb`?

To be clear, my goal isn't to manually call partitioning/formatting tools such as `newfs_msdos` from command line. I want to get exactly the same result as if "Erase.." button was pressed in `Settings` via GUI, but using a command line to achieve that.

Comment: Nope. It's not possible.

Comment: You can do it by clicking on the screen from adb. like `adb shell input touchscreen tap x y`

Comment: Settings -> Storage -> Erase SD card. https://www.wikihow.com/Format-an-SD-Card-on-Android